# How to overlap images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

my code is working properly, but after the output of my images i want them to overlap each other a bit, that might be using margins, padding or any other script, and is there a possiblity to add z-index beacuse these images should overlap, each other.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <title>Petroleum Project</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="css/shop-item.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/home.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head> 

<body>

<div id="main">
<nav id="nav01"></nav> 
 <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>

                <a class="navbar-brand" href="home.html">Home</a>
                <!--<a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"><img src="images/main-icon.jpg" style="width:80px;"/></a>-->
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Layers_Lib</a>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="well_formation.html">Well Formation</a>
            </div>
            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.container -->
    </nav> 
    <!-- Page Content --> 
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4" >
                <div class="thumbnail" style='padding-left:20px;' >
                    <div class="caption-full" >
                    <center><h2><strong>Well Formation Inputs</strong></h2></center>
                    </div>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <h4><b>Enter Height of the well:</b><input type="text" id="well_height"></h4>
            <h4><b>Select Layers:</b>
            <select multiple="true" id="layers_box">
                  <option value="conglomerate">Conglomerate</option>
                  <option value="gravel">Gravel</option>
                  <option value="sandstone">Sandstone</option>
                  <option value="siltstone">Siltstone</option>
                  <option value="shale">Shale</option>
                  <option value="clay">Clay</option>
                  <option value="limeStone">LimeStone</option>
                  <option value="dolomite">Dolomite</option>
            </select> 
            </h4>
            (press and hold CTRL to select multiple layers)
            </br></br>
                    <button id="layer_submit"class="btn-info btn" ><b>Submit</b></button>
                    <button id="layer_clear"class="btn-info btn" onClick='$("#layers_box option:selected").removeAttr("selected");$("#well_height").val("");' ><b>Clear</b></button>
                </div>

                </div>
                <div class="col-md-5" id="" style="display:block">
                    <h3> Layers </h3>
                    <div id="layer_structure" style="width:402px;border:1px solid #000;margin-left:200px;">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->
    <!-- jQuery -->

    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function img_create(src, alt, height) {

            var img= document.createElement('img');
            img.src= src;
            if (alt!=null) img.alt= alt;
            img.style.width = '400px';
            img.style.height = height+'px';
            $("#layer_structure").append(img);

        }

        jQuery(document).ready(function(){
            $("#layer_submit").click(function() {  
                    height_of_well = $("#well_height").val();
                    hw = parseInt(height_of_well);
                    if(height_of_well == ""){
                        alert("Please Enter Height of Well");
                        return false;
                    }
                    console.log(height_of_well);
                    layers = $("#layers_box").val();
                    layer_heights = [];
                    $("#layer_structure").html("");
                    $("#layer_structure").css("height",height_of_well+"px");
                    for(i = 0; i< layers.length; i++){
                      layer_heights[i] = prompt("Please Enter height of" +layers[i],"");
                      hw = hw - parseInt(layer_heights[i]);
                      if(hw < 0){
                            alert("Well height is less than layers height");
                            return false;
                      }
                      img_create("images/well_formation/"+layers[i]+".png",layers[i],layer_heights[i]);
                    }
            });
        });

    </script>

    <style>
        .list-group{
            background-color:#337ab7;
        }
    </style>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you please make a [plunk](http://plnkr.co/)?

Comment: Create [Demo](http://www.jsfiddle.net) to get your solution, also no CSS no solution.

Answer (score 2):

Overlapping in CSS can be done like this. The top image should have a `z-index` that is greater than the image below. And also, those elements must have a `position` set.

```css
.frame{
  position:relative;
}
.frame img{
  width: 100%;
  position:absolute;
}
.frame img#gabe{
  z-index: 10; 
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
.frame img#hl3{
  z-index: 9;  
}
```

```html
<div class="frame">
  <img id="gabe" src="http://www.indiavision.com/news/images/articles/2013_01/386025/u8_Gabe-Newell.jpg">
  <img id="hl3" src="http://masterherald.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/Half-Life-3.jpg">
</div>
```